# Catch python exception thrown from TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, exception

I’m running a python (v 3.6.5) code that is using TensorFlow (v 1.13.2) to perform inference using a trained model (on Windows 8.1).

**I want to catch (and log) exceptions/errors that are thrown from inside TensorFlow library.**

For example when the batch size (during a session.run()) is too large the process use all system memory and crash.

*My code looks like this:*

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math
from tqdm import tqdm
# …

def parse_function(image_string, frame_id):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    resize_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224, 224], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BICUBIC)
    return resize_image, frame_id


def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="prefix")
    return graph


def main(_):
    batch_size = 128

    num_frames = 5000
    num_batches = int(np.ceil(num_frames / batch_size))
    frame_ids = get_ids()

    with MyFrameReader() as frd:
        im_list = []
        for id in frame_ids:
            im_list.append(frd.get_frame(id))

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((im_list, frame_ids))
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
    batched_dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    iterator = batched_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    graph = load_graph(PB_FILE)
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/input_image:0')
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/output_node:0')
    sess1 = tf.Session(graph=graph)
    sess2 = tf.Session(config= tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0})) # Run on CPU
    sess2.run(iterator.initializer)

    for _ in tqdm(range(num_batches)):
        try:
            # pre process
            inference_batch, frame_id_batch = sess2.run(next_element)
            # main process
            scores_np = sess1.run(y, feed_dict={x: inference_batch})
            # post process …
        except MemoryError as e:
            print('Error 1')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error 2')
        except tf.errors.OpError as e:
            print('Error 3')
        except:
            print('Error 4')
    sess1.close()
    sess2.close()
```

I see that memory of the process grows and at some point it dies without reaching the exception handling code.
(if I add code in python that leeks memory I manage to catch a memory exception)

Can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think the problem comes from the fact that you're expecting standard python exception when the exceptions raised by tensorflow should be custom ones from there right https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/errors ? 
I think you should give us an example traceback you're getting

Comment: I dont get a traceback. The process dies and I see only this on the console: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: So that's a system exit, the only way i see this to work is to call a subprocess at each iteration and get its exit code, but i've no idea how to implement it with tensorflow sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

This should be caused by catching incorrect exceptions. Tensorflow defines its own [exceptions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/errors) which are subclasses of Exception ([source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py))

Comment: It does not catrch even if I try to catch tf.errors.ResourceExhaustedError nor tf.errors.OpError. If I catch Exception I expecting to catch also it's derived classes i.e. tf.errors.OpError and other tensorflow exceptions